# C++: why does calling std::wstring::begin() before #include <vector> cause a compiler error in this code?

Tags: c++, templates, stl

This code:

```
#include <string>

void blah() {
    std::string str;
    str.begin();
}

#include <vector>

template <template <class...> class T, class U, class V, class ... Rest>
T<V> foo(const T<U, Rest...> &container, const V &arg) {
    (void)container;
    return T<V>({arg});
}

int main() {
    auto result = foo(std::vector<int>{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, std::string("asdf"));
    return 0;
}
```

produces the following error on line 17 (the line that calls `foo()`) when compiled with clang:

```
main.cpp:17:23: error: no matching function for call to 'foo'
        auto result = foo(std::vector<int>{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, std::string("asdf"));
                      ^~~
main.cpp:11:10: note: candidate template ignored: substitution failure [with T = vector, U = int, V = std::__1::basic_string<char>, Rest = <std::__1::allocator<int>>]: too few template arguments for class template 'vector'
    T<V> foo(const T<U, Rest...> &container, const V &arg) {
    ~    ^
```

However, if I move `#include <vector>` to the top of the file, the error goes away.

Why does this happen, and is there any way to work around it while a) maintaining the position of these `#include` statements and b) not having to rewrite `foo`?

#### Explanation:

This is relevant to a library I'm working on, because it makes it necessary to include my header before certain other headers that define inline functions that call `std::string::begin()`. I'd like to avoid that requirement if at all possible, especially since it's quite likely someone might nonchalantly include these other headers before mine (as it's not usually necessary to include headers in a specific order), resulting in this error to which there's no obvious fix. The offending "other headers" are in Qt's core library, and include `<QString>`.

My library requires defining functions that take a template-template parameters with an uncertain number of template arguments, hence my usage of `template <class...> class T` and why I can't rewrite `foo`.

Note that the only STL class that seems to have this issue is `std::vector`. If I change line 17 to use `std::list`, `std::set`, or one of the other STL container classes, there's no error.

edit: Since people are reporting that other compilers aren't throwing an error, I'll add that my compiler is: Apple LLVM version 8.0.0 (clang-800.0.42.1) on macOS 10.11.6.

edit2: Updated the example code to more closely match my actual use case. Before this edit `foo` didn't return a value, but in my library it does and needs to rely on default template arguments, so the solution proposed by @n.m. unfortunately doesn't help me.

Comment: I am not seeing any problems with `g++ 5.4.0`.

Comment: This builds just fine with ToT libc++ (and either Apple clang or ToT clang), but fails with libc++ 3.8 (ish)

Comment: My compiler is Apple LLVM version 8.0.0 (clang-800.0.42.1) on macOS 10.11.6.

Comment: Looks like a compiler/library bug to me, why not file it?

Comment: @n.m. Do you know where the correct place to file it is? Not sure if I should use Apple's bug reporter, llvm.org/bugs/, or something else. llvm.org requires an account that I can't currently sign up for.

Answer (score 1):

You can work around this issue like this:

```
template <template <class...> class T, class U, class ... Rest>
void foo(const T<U, Rest...> &container) {
   (void)container;
}
```

I'm no longer sure it's a compiler/library bug. Perhaps the opposite is true (that is, compilers that do *not* emit a diagnostic message for the original code are in error). This part of the standard is rather convoluted and I'm not sure how to read it. The proposed fix seems to be correct regardless.

Comment: This almost fixed it, but it turns out I distilled down my issue into example code a little too much. I should have written foo like so: `template <template <class...> class T, class U, class V> T<V> foo (const T<U> &container, const V &value)`. I've updated my question accordingly. Can you think of any other workarounds that work for this situation?

Comment: I'm afraid you will have to specify alocators explicitly in this case.

Comment: OK. I think what I'll do as a stopgap is check for the include guard for the header file that triggers this error (QString.h) and throw an error saying my header must be included first. It's not great but at least it'll let the user know what's going on.