# Strange behaviour of default template-argument in a template-template-parameter

Tags: c++, c++11, variadic-templates, template-templates

Consider this C++11 program:

```
#include <iostream>

template <class A, class B = char> struct Cont {
    Cont () { std::cout << sizeof(B); }
};

template <template<class, class = int> class C, class E> class Wrap1
{
    C<E> ce;
};

template <template<class, class = int> class C, class... E> class Wrap2
{
    C<E...> ce;
};

int main ()
{
    Wrap1<Cont, void> w1;
    Wrap2<Cont, void> w2;
}
```

When compiled with either gcc or clang, the output is `41`.

Is this behaviour according to the standard? Where exactly does the standard specify it (for both `Wrap1` and `Wrap2`)?

This question is inspired in part by [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40881064/c-why-does-calling-stdwstringbegin-before-include-vector-cause-a-com/40896466?noredirect=1#comment69009219_40896466).

Comment: ICC and MSVC produces `44`. I'm going to go with bug.

Comment: Suppose it's compiler implementation specific.

Answer (score 1):

In Wrap2 class, parameter pack "class... E" will replace all the parameters specified by "class C" ( include the default "int" parameter), so "Wrap2 w2" will return 1 which is the default parameter of struct Cont.

Parameter pack replaced all the parameters of class C, so the default parameters of C didn't work here.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>

template <class A=char, class B = short, class C = int> struct MyTest
{
    MyTest ()
    {
        std::cout << sizeof(A) << " " << typeid(A).name() << " ";
        std::cout << sizeof(B) << " " << typeid(B).name() << " ";
        std::cout << sizeof(C) << " " << typeid(C).name() << std::endl;
    }
};

template <template<class = double, class = double, class = double> class D, class E, class... F> class Wrap
{
    D<E> de; // the parameters of D is: E + default parameters of D.
    D<F...> df; // the parameters of D is: F... + default parameters of MyTest, the default parameter of D don't work, it will be replaced by pack F.
};

int main ()
{
    Wrap<MyTest, int, int> w;
}

//g++ 5.4.0
//output:
//4 i 8 d 8 d
//4 i 2 s 4 i
```

Comment: I can see what happens, I'm asking where in the standard this behaviour is defined.